# Basic functional derivative question

Tags: mathematical-physics, calculus-of-variations

I've just started to learn mathematical physics, and I read [Stone and Goldbart's Mathematics for Physics](http://www.goldbart.gatech.edu/PostScript/MS_PG_book/bookmaster.pdf). But I couldn't understand on page 16 right at the beginning, they said this:

> **1.2.1. The functional derivative:**
>
> We restrict ourselves to expressions of the form
>
> $$J[y] = \int_{x_1}^{x_2} f[ \, x, y, y',y'',...y^{(n)} ] \, dx $$
>
> Consider a functional $J=\int f dx$ in which f depends only on $x, y$ and $y'$. Make a change $y(x) \rightarrow y(x) + \epsilon \eta (x)$, where $\epsilon$ is a (small) $x$-indipendent constant. The resultant change in J is:
> $$\begin{align} J[y+\epsilon \eta]-J[y] &=\int_{x_1}^{x_2}\{f(x,y+\epsilon \eta,y'+\epsilon \eta')-f(x,y,y')\}dx \\ &= \int_{x_1}^{x_2} \{\epsilon \eta\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}+\epsilon\frac{d\eta}{dx}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y'}+O(\epsilon^2)\}\\ &= ......(this part Iunderstand)\end{align} $$

I can't really wrap my head around this. What is that $\eta(x)$ that suddenly showed up? How did they manage from the first line to the second line in the above expression? And why is there a big-O at the end? (If you don't have the book you can actually find on page 16 [right here](http://www.goldbart.gatech.edu/PostScript/MS_PG_book/bookmaster.pdf), the next part is just an integration by part)

It'd be awesome if someone can explain this to me please? Thank you! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick and formal answer: for a smooth function,
$$
F(x+\varepsilon) = F(x) + \varepsilon F'(x) + O(\varepsilon^2),
$$
as a consequence of a Taylor expansion. Hence
$$
f(x,y+\varepsilon\eta,y'+\varepsilon \eta') = f(x,y) + \varepsilon \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \eta + \varepsilon\frac{\partial f}{\partial y'}\eta' + O(\varepsilon^2).
$$